# How to set the default font for a NSTextView?

Tags: swift, nstextview

I'm using a textView with "Rich Text" option disabled to display some plain text. I can't find a way to set the default font. If I put in some text in IB (which I don't want anyway) I can then set the font in IB interface, but when users delete the font and start to type, the text changes to a different font and size. I read some questions and answers here and developer documentation without find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the exact name of the font you want to use, like for this case "AvenirNextCondensed"

```
let tv = NSTextView()
tv.font = NSFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-Regular", size: 15.0)!
```

If you want to use the system font of size whatever, do it like this (where `size` is a `CGFloat`)

```
tv.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: size)
```

Comment: I would like to use the system font whatever, at a size of 15.

Comment: @Tel - See my updated answer for how to use the system font with different sizes.